# MobClix ads not showing up

Tags: android, mobclix

I have created MobClix account, made sure I have filled up all kinds of settings (account, payment everything), Added the app, carefully copied the Application ID.  Made sure I have activated Full screen and 320x50 ads on test modes.

Then I followed the developer guide and placed this in my activity:

```
<com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixMMABannerXLAdView
    android:id="@+id/mainScreenBannerAd"
    android:layout_width="320dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip" >
</com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixMMABannerXLAdView>
```

and in the respective Class:

```
MobclixMMABannerXLAdView mx=(MobclixMMABannerXLAdView)findViewById(R.id.mainScreenBannerAd);
mx.getAd();
```

I also have this in the same class:

```
MobclixFullScreenAdView adview = new MobclixFullScreenAdView(this);
adview.requestAndDisplayAd();
```

The second code snippet triggers a fullscreen ad view and a Test Ad banner is displayed, the first one however doesn't seem to do anything and nothing is showing inside the activity. I have made sure that the 320x50 banner ad view is in the activity and taking up space by placing different color background views before and after that.  I am sure that its there but not displaying anything.

Has anyone got through such a situation?

**TL DR:**  One of the MobClix ads show fine (fullscreen), the one in activity doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you submitted a support ticket? You can do so, here: http://support.mobclix.com/requests/new

Let me know your ticket # and I'll be sure the support team gets back to you with an answer soon!

Thanks,
Barbara @ Mobclix

Comment: I'm glad MobClix official support guys keep a watch here. Thanks Barbara.  The number is 9319

TO maintain the format and purpose of stackoverflow, I will post whatever solution I was offered as an answer so others could take help from that.

Comment: Sure, no problem! Michael, who's the lead support person here, will be reaching out to you shortly. Also, feel free to e-mail Navang Oza (noza at velti dot com) if you have any more questions, as he can help as well. Hope to get you up and running asap!

Comment: must say your support is intense and you deserve five star rating for that.  I am co-ordinating with Michael and post conclusion here.

BTW, in the PDF documentation that is downloaded alongwith SDK, I guess there's an error where it says

MobclixFullScreenAdView adview = new MobclixFullScreenAdView(this);
fsAdView.requestAndDisplayAd();

I think in line 2, fsAdView should be replaced by adview.  Please get it checked, code is not running without this correction